# How to disable "related videos" from an embedded vimeo playlist

Tags: vimeo

I need to embed a vimeo playlist on an iframe. I don't want the user to be able to access other videos. the related videos showing in the end. how can be remove this?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run into cross-domain policy issues trying to edit external content from outside of an iframe. You can load the video page link (given in the iframe embed) using javascript and delete .vp-outro-wrapper and maybe .vp-cards-wrapper after it loads. I'm not 100% sure those are the right elements, but it'll be the same idea.